# Hadoop 2.x cluster node manager not getting started in slave nodes

Tags: apache, hadoop, hadoop2

i am trying to setup a multi node hadoop 2.x cluster in Virtual machine,after the setup and configurations,while i try to start the cluster,node manager is not getting started in slave nodes,all other daemons are get started in the cluster,can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/hadoop-2.6.0/data/nnode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/hadop-2.6.0/data/dnode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/exclude</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.hosts.include</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/include</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.include-path</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/include</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path</name>
        <value>/home/hduser/exclude</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>master</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Add logs or/and config for your question, please.

Comment: i have added the configuration file, log file just show up the ulimit values no errors at all ...

Comment: Does your slave nodes know the alias master ?. Could you please share the error logs from the nodemanager in slave

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your configuration:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
</property>
```

Node Manager is a component of YARN, on startup, this component registers with the RM. If "master" is not resolved to a valid ip address the Node Manager can't contact the resource manager.
Status is not pulled by the Resource Manager, instead is pushed by the datanodes to RM.

I think you should investigate this.